# What are the best practices of updating multiple divs with ActionCable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I have a Ruby on Rails site. One of the index pages has a table with multiple rows. I also have a background job that does certain operations on each row, which takes about 5-10 seconds each.

I would like to update the status for each row from 'Processing...' to 'Done' when the processing in the background job has completed.

I was thinking to use Action Cable to do the update, but to date I only used Action Cable to update only one element on a page, never multiple elements.

I was wondering what the correct way is to set-up my code to update the status in each row. Do I have to open a channel for each row separately?

Comment: see https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record if it helps

Comment: Hello,

you would not open up a channel for each row of your table, You just broadcast to the channel for the page after each set is updated.  

With ActionCable you can get back an object(s) in JSON.  you can then use javascript to loop through that list and update your UI (based on id, or other unique bit of information). Or you can get back a json response containing HTML and replace the row. Here are some good guides for action cable https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html, https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely You can do so. And you don't have to open channel for each row. Just use the job id whose status has been changed and id corresponding row in table with same id.

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "job_status_update", job_id: 'xxxxx', status: 'complete'
```

## .html

```
<table>
  <% jobs.each do |job|%>
   <tr>
     <td id="<%= job_id %>">
     <%= job.status %>
     </td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

## .coffee

```
App.chatChannel = App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "JobChannel" },
   received: (data) ->
     $(data.job_id).innerText(data.status)
```

Comment: Both Guadam's answer and Kick's answers worked. Thank you!